# Bootstrap Navbar does not want to show dot separator between elements

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am making site with Django 3.1.2 and Bootstrap 4.5.3. I have some issues with navbar.

[image]

I want to have these links on the right separated by middle dots.
This piece of css does not run correctly - only padding works, dot is not visible:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
   content: "\00B7";
   padding-right: 35px;
}
```

This is how this section looks like in the html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item nav-link">      
            <a href="{% url 'blog:about' %}" class="menu">O Szkole</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-link">  
            <a href="{% url 'blog:teachers' %}" class="menu">Kadra</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-link">  
            <a href="#" class="menu">Kalendarz</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-link">  
            <a href="{% url 'blog:projects' %}" class="menu">Projekty</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-link">  
            <a href="{% url 'blog:contact' %}" class="menu">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item nav-link">  
            <a href="#" class="menu">Informacje dla uczniów</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-link">  
            <a href="#" class="menu">Informacje dla rodziców</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-link">  
            <a href="#" class="menu">Dokumenty</a>
        </li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="#">Nowy Post</a>
            <a href="#">Wyloguj się</a>
            <a>Witaj: user.username</a>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right: 35px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item:not(:last-child) ::after {
    content: "\00B7";
}
```

content works only with the pseudoelements ::after and ::before